# Logical "Except" operator for If statements in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, logical-operators

FYI, I'm new to using R so my code is likely quite clunky. I've done my homework on this but haven't been able to find an "Except" logical operator for R and really need something like that in my code. My input data is a .csv containing integers and null values with 12 columns and 1440 rows.

```
oneDayData <- read.csv("data.csv") # Loading data
oneDayMatrix <- data.matrix(oneDayData, rownames.force = NA) #turning data frame into     a matrix


rowBefore <- data.frame(oneDayData[i-1,10], stringsAsFactors=FALSE) # Creating a variable to be used in the if statement, represents cell before the cell in the loop

ctr <- 0 # creating a counter and zeroing it


for (i in 1:nrow(oneDayMatrix)) {
  if ((oneDayMatrix[i,10] == -180) & (oneDayMatrix[i,4] == 0)) { # Makes sure that there is missing data matched with a zero in activityIn
    impute1 <- replace(oneDayMatrix[ ,10], oneDayMatrix[i,10], rowBefore)
    ctr <- (ctr + 1) # Populating the counter with how many rows get changed
  }
  else{
    print("No data fit this criteria.")
  }
}
print(paste(ctr, "rows have been changed.")) # Printing the counter and number of rows that got changed enter code here
```

I would like to add some kind of EXCEPT condition to my if statement or equivalent that says something like: employ the two previous conditions (see if statement in code) EXCEPT when oneDayMatrix[i-1, 4] > 0. I would really appreciate any help with this and thank you in advance!

Comment: You just write the appropriate logical expression.  Note that your exception doesn't make sense when `i=1`.

Comment: `rowBefore <- ...` uses the undefined `i`.

Comment: Thank you so much. There was obviously a lot of bugs and you've all been extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Except" is equivalent to "if not". The "not" operator in R is `!`. So to add that `oneDayMatrix[i-1, 4] > 0` exception, you just need to modify your `if` statement as follows:

```
if ((oneDayMatrix[i,  10] == -180) &
    (oneDayMatrix[i,   4] ==  0)   &
   !(oneDayMatrix[i-1, 4]  >  0)) { ... }
```

or equivalently:

```
if ((oneDayMatrix[i,  10] == -180) &
    (oneDayMatrix[i,   4] ==  0)   &
    (oneDayMatrix[i-1, 4] <=  0)) { ... }
```

This goes on top of a couple fixes that need to be made to your code:

1. as I pointed out, `rowBefore` is not defined properly: in terms of `i` which is not defined yet. Inside your `for` loop, just replace `rowBefore` with `oneDayMatrix[i-1, 10]`
2. as @noah pointed out, you need to start your loop at the second index: `for (i in 2:nrow(oneDayMatrix))`.